# Extract date from string in shell script

Tags: shell, date, extract

I want to get a date which is in a string with shell script for an example:

```
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaSun Apr 07 10:38:34 EEST 2013jnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
```

How I can extract a date which is in a string with shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your example text is really reflecting your real data. And I think the `EEST` is a typo? If work on the example you gave:

```
dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
dddddddddddddddansdpaSun Apr 07 10:38:34 EEST 2013jnad
dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
```

this line should do the job:

```
grep -o '[A-Z].*[0-9]'
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaSun Apr 07 10:38:34 EEST 2013jnad
    dddddddddddddddansdpaojhndpaosdjnad"|grep -o '[A-Z].*[0-9]'
Sun Apr 07 10:38:34 EEST 2013
```