# Compare date via shell script

Tags: shell, date

I have this text:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddd
sadasdafnsdfoisjhpfnsf
dasnfdfmsdf until: Thu Apr 29 19:41:02 EEST 2021 dasd
asdasmda[mfiun[hg[sm df,
dfmsdf[ismdfsdfsd,flsdfsdf******************
```

I have to parse a date from a text and after that I have to compare it with today and if it greater to do something otherwise I have to do something else and I have to write it in shell script but I do not now it very well. Can someone give me a example how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract date from string in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523263/extract-date-from-string-in-shell-script)

Comment: There's a good deal of overlap with your previous question.

Comment: I managed to parse the date from the string and set a variables for the day, month, week_day, year and etc. but when I try to echo them only blank lines were show in the shell

Comment: Please show that code. It sounds like you may have set the variables in a subshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in two steps. (it could be done in one):

1, get the date string
2, do comparison

e.g.:

```
 kent$  d=$(echo "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddd
sadasdafnsdfoisjhpfnsf
dasnfdfmsdf until: Thu Apr 29 19:41:02 EEST 2021 dasd
asdasmda[mfiun[hg[sm df,
dfmsdf[ismdfsdfsd,flsdfsdf******************"|grep -o '[A-Z].*[0-9]')
```

check the var d:

```
kent$  echo $d
Thu Apr 29 19:41:02 EEST 2021
```

now we compare this date to today. we need convert both dates into seconds to do comparison:

```
kent$  echo $(($(date -d"${d}" +%s)-$(date +%s)))
251171977
```

I printed the result of above command out. In your case, you could just assign it to a var. or just check the result directly. if it >0 means the date in your text in future. otherwise, it is in the past(or same as today).

**EDIT**

some math:

with int:

```
kent$  echo $((251171977/(3600*24)))
2907
```

with precision:

```
kent$  echo "scale=2;251171977/(3600*24)"|bc 
2907.08
```

more precisely:

```
kent$  echo "scale=7;251171977/(3600*24)"|bc                                                                                                                                
2907.0830671
```

Comment: how to convert the seconds to days and echo them?

Comment: @JordanBorisov, well... you have x seconds, and now I ask you, the x seconds are how many days? shall I **really** explain this to you?

Comment: the problem is how to do it in shell script? Of course I know the method :)

Answer (score 1):

If possible, print the date in a form that is easier to parse. i.e.

```
`echo "the day of the year is `date '+%j'`"`
```

This makes comparisons much easier.